# Pegando hora no formato: HORA:MINUTO:SEGUNDO

Tags: java, android

Atualmente utilizo esse código:

```
// Pega a hora
Date hora = new Date();
hora.getTime();
```

Ele me retorna isso:

> Thu Aug 28 21:55:42 BRT 2014

Gostaria de um jeito de pegar somente hora, minuto e segundo. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma forma bem simples é usar um `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date hora = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // Ou qualquer outra forma que tem
String dataFormatada = sdf.format(hora);
```

Como esta usando a tag Android, recomendo a documentação da plataforma Android para o [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) que tem alguns detalhes que a plataforma Java pode não ter.

Se precisar trabalhar com o locale do dispositivo para data, da uma olhada na documentação que vai te ajudar.

Como alertado, ao usar o SimpleDateFormat no Android, o `lint` recomenda usar o `Locale`.

Uma das soluções seria:

```
// Isso era buscar o locale do dispositivo
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
```

Outras formas são:

```
SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance()
// ou
SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstace(int style);
// ou
SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(int style, Locale locale);
```

O atributo `style` pode assumir um dos valores:

```
DateFormat.FULL
DateFormat.LONG
DateFormat.MEDIUM
DateFormat.SHORT
DateFormat.DEFAULT
```

Só como exemplo de formatação, o resultado para cada estilo é:

```
DateFormat.FULL -> 10:46:28 PM Brasilia Standard Time
DateFormat.LONG -> 10:46:28 PM GMT-03:00
DateFormat.MEDIUM -> 10:46:28 PM
DateFormat.SHORT -> 10:46 PM
DateFormat.DEFAULT -> 10:46:28 PM
```

Comment: isso mesmo que estava procurando :), so que ao utilizar o SDF, me veio um aviso:

Comment: "To get local formatting use getDateInstance(), getDateTimeInstance(), or getTimeInstance(), or use new SimpleDateFormat(String template, Locale locale) with for example Locale.US for ASCII dates."

Comment: @Josinaldo, valeu pelo aviso, não tinha me atentado a isso na documentação. Vou incluir isso e a diferença dos `styles`.

Comment: Resolvido: ("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())

Comment: @Josinaldo, inclui o resultado usando os `styles`, creio que não atende ao seu requisito, mas é só para exemplificar o uso deles.

Comment: melhor ainda, irei precisar futuramente :)

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Brazil/East"));
int ano = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); // O mês vai de 0 a 11.
int semana = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
int dia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hora = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minuto = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int segundo = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```